# How do I use the default 'Internal Azure DNS' to resolve DNS names of worker roles within the same Azure Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have a cloud service that has a worker role 'Kernel' with 2 instances (instance 0, and instance 1). I have another VM deployed in a different subnet, in the same Azure Virtual Network. I heard that I can use Azure DNS to resolve a hostname to get the private (dynamic) IP address of each worker role. But how do I actually do that? I assume on the client side this is just a standard DNS lookup, so the question is really: what do I put in the CSCFG file, and what FQDN DNS name is actually what I should resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the name on the worker role VMs, add vmName to the cscfg as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156212.aspx

The two workers will have a common DNS suffix so you can just refer to them by name.  To find the FQDN you'll either need to login to one of the VMs and do ipconfig /all or use the powershell Get-AzureVM cmdlet with the -Debug switch and look for InternalDnsSuffix.

Regards
Gareth [MSFT]

Comment: Great, thanks! By the way, I have been wondering, are there details of SLA for internal Azure DNS? And how long should it take for the record to get updated if the dynamic IP of a role changes (as sometimes happens)?

Comment: I actually could not find an internal DNS name anywhere in the response of the Get-AzureVM cmdlet. What should I be looking for exactly?

Comment: You will need to add the vmName to the CSCFG for the role and deploy before InternalDnsSuffix appears in the output.  It's in the Deployment, usually at the bottom.  Here's some PS to help find it:  $x = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName idnsworkertestwithvmname  -Debug 5>&1;
$y = $x | where {$_ -ilike "*InternalDns*"};$y.Message.Split("`n") | where {$_ -ilike "*InternalDns*"}

Comment: Ah, that must be the problem - that deployment was one not created with the vmName in the CSCFG. Thanks again!